# eclipse checkstyle error cannot initialize module TreeWalker - TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of RegexpHeader

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle version 5.6.1 .I get this error when I try to use a user defined check style template :

cannot initialize module TreeWalker - TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of RegexpHeader

Answer (score 1):

Probably your configuration is similar to the following one:

```
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="RegexpHeader">
      ...
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

You need to change it to:

```
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="RegexpHeader">
    ...
  </module>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    ...
  </module>
</module>
```

because *TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of RegexpHeader*.